# How to navigate to a method from another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, class, methods

I have mainLogin and loginPage classes. From the mainLogin class, I want to navigate to method inside loginPage but I am having an error. Here's my code.

This one's from the mainLogin

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => loginPage()._showRegistrationForm(context),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'SIGN UP',
                      style: TextStyle(color: getColorFromHex('#055ffa')),

                    ),
                  ),
```

and this one's from the loginPage class

```
class loginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPage createState() => _LoginPage();
}

class _LoginPage extends State<loginPage>{

  var fname, lname, uname, email, password, token;

  bool _showPassword = false;

  _showRegistrationForm(context){

        ....// code here
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your onTap code with my code:

onTap: () => Navigator.push(
context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loginPage())),

Comment: Hi! Thanks but I kinda want to navigate to _showRegistrationForm inside of loginPage class.